# Error in nginx: 2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to start frontend and backend in docker-compose and use nginx.

For a long time I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and why I'm getting errors due to nginx and how it can be fixed.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "smeldb"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    networks:
      - backend

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    #    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --reload
    tty: true
    environment:
      DB_NAME: "smeldb"
      DB_USER: "postres"
      DB_PASSWORD: "postres"
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_HOST: postgres
      SERVER_HOST: "0.0.0.0"
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/data
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      - backend

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: client_frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true


volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream frontend {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 32M;

    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "*" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS" always;


    location /api {
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        proxy_redirect     default;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
#

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

and when i start connect to http://localhost/ i catch 502 Bad Gateway.

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

```
2023/04/27 21:04:03 [warn] 8#8: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

```
2023/04/27 21:04:03 [error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

```
2023/04/27 21:04:03 [warn] 8#8: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

What i do wrong ?

How to fix that? Or whot i do wrong?

Comment: The username and the password are "postres", maybe it's a typo and should be "postgres"?

Comment: In the `upstream frontend` declaration, you're telling the Nginx proxy to connect to `localhost`, that is, itself.  You probably need the Compose service name of the other container, `server frontend:3000`.

Comment: @DavidMaze if i try this, i catch ``` host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:26
 nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:26
```